# Applying for British citizenship for under-18 born outside UK

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

My boy is under 18 and wants to apply for British Citizenship.

He was born outside UK but moved here when he was one year old. He has lived and studied in UK for the last 16 years and has ILR since 2009 along with us. We, his parents, do not want to apply for British citizenship for various reasons.

Does he need to apply with MN1 Form? What are his avenues for citizenship since the options in MN1 form are not very clear for under-18 born outside UK whose parents are not applying for citizenship as well.

Comment: It sounds like he's almost 18.  Why not wait until then?

Comment: It's a heck of a lot cheaper for one reason. Also, an entitlement is a bit more fundamentally sound than a regular application.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, citizenship by means of Entitlement can never stripped under any circumstance. It can only be renounced. Those who have acquired citizenship by regular application can have their citizen taken away. But that part of my comment is irrelevant now that I think about it. MN1 via 3(1) is the only possibility here, and I do not believe that this is an entitlement. It is solely by discretion, so forget that part. But it is a lot cheaper.

Comment: There's no appeal. There's reconsideration, which I believe is £80. It's if you decide to take it to JR that its outrageous and obviously more than the regular route. I'd probably wait until 18 and take fewer chances (assuming that all else i.e. residency, good character, etc are all in order).

Comment: I have no idea about all this but if someone puts all this in an answer it could be useful to explain if there is any prejudice attached to a failed MN1 application (can you still try again easily after you turn 18?).

Comment: @Relaxed, no prejudice. They really do not like to refuse MN1 applications if there is any way possible to avoid it. Unlike immigration, it's bad for policy. The risk is that they will think the OP has touched upon some points raised in the precedent based scenarios and pass it along to the discretionary team. That makes it an insufferably long process and the OP would most likely withdraw the app when they turned 18 and had a clear shot.  No refund + it takes a while for them to  cancel it. Discretion is helpful for people who have no other choice and are willing to wait for a long time.

Comment: @Relaxed, all the comments are lined up that it's better to wait until the OP is 18.  Do you still think this needs a formal 'answer'?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [Form MN guide book](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/437170/mn1_guide_june_2015.pdf) it seems that the child's options are limited, at least without one parent being a British citizen.

Working through the categories in that document, the only one that seems to apply is the item titled "Any other child born to British or non-British parents" on page 14. There, point 4 in the list says:

> The parents’ nationality and immigration status – we expect either both parents to be British citizens **or** one parent a British citizen and the other parent settled in the UK.

Given this, it seems that you'd be relying entirely on discretion rather than entitlement.

I'd suggest discussing the situation with a lawyer or possibly your local citizen's advice bureau to get a better idea of the chance of success